# Describe a random variable with MGF $\frac{1}{2-M(t)}$ where $M(t)$ is the MGF of $X$

Tags: probability-theory, moment-generating-functions

If the MGF of random variable $X$ is denoted by $M(t)$, find a random variable which has the MGF $$\frac{1}{2-M(t)}.$$

I have tried to solve this problem using the Taylor series, but it did not work well!

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please read this text about [how to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question).

Comment: What is $M(t)$?

Comment: M(t) is the MGF of a variable X. It means if the new MGF is $\frac{1}{2-M(t)}$ what is the new variable

Answer (score 0):

Answer:

$\frac{1}{2-M(t)}=\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{M(t)^k}{2^{k+1}}=\sum_{k=0}^\infty E[e^{t\sum_{n=0}^N X_n}|N=k]P[N=k]$.

where N is Geometric(0.5).